# android unable to start receiver java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

i created appwidget and i try to show json's items'(image's and text) in my appwidget(stackview widget) i successfully created app widget and i also can show json in widget but when i should click in widget i have error NullPointerException

this is a my code :

```
public class BriGeRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    return new BriGeRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}

static class BriGeRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    public static ArrayList<ItemI> itemList;
    private static Context context;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public BriGeRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
                    itemList = new ArrayList<ItemI>();
        this.appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        itemList = getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        itemList = getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        itemList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        ItemI item = itemList.get(position);

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.item_view);

        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettitle, item.getTitle());

        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img, getImageBitmap(item.getImage()));

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(BriGeWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
        Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
        fillIntent.putExtras(extras);

        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.item_root, fillIntent);

        return rv;
    }

    private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    private static ArrayList<ItemI> getData() {
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(context);
        return jp.getDataAsList();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class BriGeWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static final String TOAST_ACTION = "com.example.android.stackwidget.TOAST_ACTION";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "com.example.android.stackwidget.EXTRA_ITEM";
private RemoteViews views;
private Intent intent;


@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {

        int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);

        ItemI item = BriGeRemoteViewsFactory.itemList.get(viewIndex);

        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, WidgetResult.class)
                .putExtra("KEY_title", item.getTitle())
                .putExtra("KEY_desc", item.getDescription())

                .putExtra("KEY_tabula", item.getJournal())
                .putExtra("KEY_datetime", item.getPubDate())
                .putExtra("KEY_image", item.getImage())
                .putExtra("KEY_startID", item.getStatID())

                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        intent = new Intent(context, BriGeRemoteViewsService.class);

        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.stackWidgetView, intent);

        views.setEmptyView(R.id.stackWidgetView, R.id.stackWidgetEmptyView);

        Intent templateIntent = new Intent(context,
                BriGeWidgetProvider.class);
        templateIntent.setAction(BriGeWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
        templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, templateIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stackWidgetView,
                templatePendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

}

Exception is this line

```
ItemI item = BriGeRemoteViewsFactory.itemList.get(viewIndex);
```

this is a WidgetResult class

```
public class WidgetResult extends Activity {
public TextView widgetTitle, widgetDescription, widgetTabula, widgetDate;
public String resulttitle, resutlTabul, resultdesc, resultimage,
        resultPutdate, resutlStartID;
public ImageView img;

private ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_result);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    widgetTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widgettitleDetails);
    widgetDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widgetdescriptionDetails);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.widgetimageDetails);
    widgetTabula = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widgetDateTimeDetails);
    widgetDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widgetTabula);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    resulttitle = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_title");
    resultdesc = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_desc");

    resutlTabul = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_tabula");
    resultimage = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_image");
    resultPutdate = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_datetime");
    resutlStartID = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_startID");

    widgetTabula.setText(resutlTabul);
    widgetTabula.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);
    String ab = resultimage.replaceAll("-c.jpg", ".jpg");

    Log.e("imageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", ab);
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

    } else {
        new DownloadTask().execute(ab);
    }

    widgetTitle.setText(resulttitle);
    widgetTitle.setTypeface(MainActivity.tf2);

    resultdesc = resultdesc.trim();

    widgetDescription.setText(resultdesc);

}

private Bitmap downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.connect();

        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }

    return bitmap;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            bitmap = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        img.setImageBitmap(result);
        Log.e("Bitmapppppppppppppppp", result.toString());

        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
        // "Image downloaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

first time app working perfect i can touch widget and i have not problem but when i close app and then should click - has a exception

if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

[My Log Cat error](http://postimg.org/image/6688yt9z1/)

Comment: Post the whole log-cat exception, including hte caused-by

Comment: this is a my logCat Error ( http://postimg.org/image/6688yt9z1/)

Comment: You need to post it as part of your question, the full exception with any caused-by's

Answer (score 0):

`itemList` in `BriGeRemoteViewsFactory` is never instantiated so when you do `BriGeRemoteViewsFactory.itemList` it is null. The fix is to instantiate by adding the below line into the constructor of `BriGeRemoteViewsFactory`

```
itemList = new ArrayList<ItemI>();
```

Comment: thank you i added this line but i have also error. i updated my post(code) and look please again

Comment: You need to cleanup the question then (remove unnecessary code and post the necessary logcat). I can't even see your new issue

Comment: i added this line ( itemList = new ArrayList<ItemI>();) the constructor of BriGeRemoteViewsFactory but i have also error